# How to use query in mongodump on embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, backup, mongodump, database

I'm trying to do a mongodump with query. Below is my syntax.

```
mongodump --db mydatabase --collection records --query '{ "embedded_document.field_1" : { "$ne" : "Zebra" }}' -vvvv
```

What I'm trying to do is dump all records with `embedded_document.field_1` that is not equal to `Zebra`.

I have 100 records with `Zebra` in it, but the count of the records found is equal to all records count (`5000`).

```
Collection File Writing Progress: 200/5000  0%      (objects)
```

The query works in mongo shell and it returns the correct count (`100`).

```
db.records.find({ "embedded_document.field_1" : { "$ne" : "Zebra" }}).count();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Cannot re-produce. A MongoDB version perhaps? Confirmed to be working as expected with 2.6.5.

Comment: @NeilLunn Hi, I'm using version `2.6.5`.

Comment: Upon testing few queries, there is no issue at all. The progress was displaying the total count of all records, but it will write the total number of your query.

Answer (score 0):

which version do you use? And what's your platform? Try this:
mongodump --db mydatabase --collection records --query "{ 'embedded_document.field_1': { '$ne' : 
'Zebra' }}" -vvvv